# Execute many long-running tasks with the "TAP" design pattern

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp, async-await, task

I'm currently developing a system where I'll need to connect a couple of clients to a server, which means that I will need to run a background task for each client. The last project I built was with [APM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/asynchronous-programming-model-apm), but I am now trying out to build everything around the new and better [TAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap).

My question is, how do I run many *long-running* asynchronous functions within a synchronous function? I know that I could use **Task.Run()**, but it feels like there's a better way. If I just try to run the function as it is, the warning ...

*"Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed."*

... appears, which means that I'm doing something wrong.. or do I? What is the most efficient and correct way to make all of the clients run at the same time?

```
class AsyncClient 
{
    public AsyncClient() 
    {
        ...
    }

    public async Task RunAsync(IPAddress address, int port)
    {
        ... waiting for data
    }
}
```

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<AsyncClient> clients = new <AsyncClient>();

    clients.Add(new AsyncClient());
    clients.Add(new AsyncClient());
    clients.Add(new AsyncClient());

    foreach (var c in clients)
    {
        // What is the best way to start every async tasks?

        c.RunAsync("127.0.0.1", "8080");

        // ^ This gives the warning "Because this call is not awaited, 
        // execution of the current method continues before the call is completed."
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How did you do it in APM?

Answer (score 3):

First you should change your `Main` method to be `async`:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
```

Then you can await the asynchronous operations.

To allow them to run in parallel, you can make use of LINQ `Select`:

```
IEnumerable<Task> tasks = clients.Select(c => c.RunAsync("127.0.0.1", "8080"));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

`Task.WhenAll` returns a new `Task` that completes when all the provided `Task`s have completed.

Without awaiting the `Task`s, there is a good chance that your `Main` method will complete, and hence the program will exit,  before the `Task`s have competed,

Comment: Hmm, that'll work, but what if I wanna process other things when these async **Tasks** are running? I'm using a *Discovery (UDP multicasting)* service which will search for available servers automatically, which will need to run at the same time as the clients. I guess I could put the service inside **Task.WhenAll(tasks)** too, but is that the standard way doing things like this?

Comment: @Warcaith You can run any logic you like between the task generation and the `Task.WhenAll`. You could await the tasks right at the end of `Main` simply to prevent the program from exiting too early.

Comment: Alright, I see how it works now! But what I'm still pretty confused about is where the async function chaining will break? It feels like you need to make every parent function *async* whenever you wanna use a library with **TAP** async functions.

Comment: @Warcaith Yes that's right; async propagates all the way to the top of the call stack. The only alternative is to block, which defeats the purpose of async.

Comment: Wouldn't these mean that every program that uses **TAP** async function would need to have *async Task Main(string[] args)* as it is at the top of the call stack? The thing is, I've seen a couple of GitHub project where the starting point is the normal *void Main(string[] args)*. Are they using the pattern wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: @Warcaith `async main` was only introduced in c# 7.1 so before that the only workaround was to block. If you are going to block the thread then the entry point is the best place to do it anyway.

Comment: @Warcaith the `async Main` is actually [syntactic sugar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main) for a synchronous, blocking, top-level call. It is used mainly with Console applications. UI applications have usually async event handlers as asynchronous entry points (for example `async void Button1_Click`).

Comment: @Johnathan Is there anywhere I can get in contact with you?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/8126362/johnathan-barclay

Comment: @Johnathan Hmm, I can't find anywhere to start the chat.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a non async method, and in this non-async method you want to call async methods.

Usually a method is async, because somewhere deep inside your thread has to wait for another lengthy process to finish. Think of a file to be written, a database query to be executed, or some information to be fetched from the internet. Those are typically functions where you'll find async methods next to the non-async methods.

Instead of waiting idly for the other process to finish its task, the caller of the method  receives control to do other things, until it sees an await. Control is given to the caller until it sees an await etc.

So if you want to do other things while the other process is executing its task: simply don't await. The problem is of course: you want to know the result of the other task, before your function exits. If you don't if will be hard to define the post condition of your method.

```
void MyMethod()
{
    Task<int> taskA = MethodAasync(...);

    // you didn't await, you are free to do something else, like calling another async method
    Task<double> taskB = MethodBasync(...);

    DoSomethingUseful();

    // if here, you need the result of taskA. Wait until it is ready
    // this blocks your thread!
    taskA.Wait();
    int resultA = taskA.Result();
    ProcessResult(resultA);

    // if desired, you can wait for a collection of tasks:
    Task[] tasksToWaitFor = new Task[] {taskA, taskB};
    Task.WaitAll(tasksToWaitFor);
    int resultA = taskA.Result();
    double resultB = taskB.Result();
    ProcessResults(resultA, resultB);
}
```

Even if you are not interested in the result of the tasks, it is wise to wait for them to finish. This allows you to react on exceptions.

By the way, did you see that I did not call `Task.Run`! What happens, is that my thread enters MethodAasync until it sees an await. Then the procedure gets back control, so it enters MethodBasync until is sees an await. Your procedure gets back control to DoSomethingUseful.

As soon as the other process (database query, write file, etc) is finished, one of the threads of the thread pool continues processing the statements after the await, until it meets a new await, or until there is nothing more to process.

`Task.Wait` and `Task.WaitAll` are the methods that stop this asynchronousness: the thread will really block until all async methods are completely finished.

There is seldom a reason to use Task.Run if you want to call an async method: simply call it, do not wait for it, so you can do other useful stuff. Make sure you Wait for the task to finish as soon as you need the result, or at the latest when you return the method.

Another method would be to return the tasks without waiting for them to finish, to give your caller the opportunity to do something useful as long as the tasks are not completed. Of course this can only be done if your procedure doesn't need the result of the task. It also obliges your caller to wait for completion, or pass the tasks to his caller.

The only reason to Task.Run that I can see, is that you want to start a lengthy procedure within your own process, that you don't want to wait for right now. Think of doing a lengthy calculations. Don't use Task.Run if another process is involved. In that case the other process should have an async function, or you should create an async extension method that does the task.Run.

```
int DoSomeLengthyCalculations(...) {...};

async Task<MyResult> CalculateIt(...)
{
    Task<int> taskLengthyCalculations = Task.Run( () => DoSomeLengthyCalculations(...);

     // if desired DoSomethingUsefull; after that wait for the task to end
     // and process the result:
     Task.Wait(taskLengthyCalculations);
     int resultLengthyCalculations = taskLengthyCalucalations.Result();
     MyResult result = ProcessResult(resultLengthyCalculations);
     return result;
}
```

The nice thing is that you've hidden whether you are doing the lengthy calculations, or that someone else is doing it. For instance if you are unit testing methods that async access a database, you can mock this while accessing a Dictionary instead.
    }

Comment: It is poor etiquette to hide `Task.Run` in an `async` method. The decision to run an asynchronous operation on the thread pool should be left to the caller, particularly if your wrapping a long running CPU bound operation, as this will still block another thread (just not the current one).

Comment: If you let the caller decide to use Task.Run, isn't he doing the same as I would do within my procedure? Why wouldn't that be poor etiquette for him?

Comment: Of course someone has to do the heavy calculations, so at least one thread will be busy doing it. The only thing is that my thread will be free to do other things instead, like calling real async methods where my thread would otherwise be waiting idly for other processes to finish

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html